# Searching period and hyphen-delimited fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search

I'm trying to find a way to use Elasticsearch to query a field that is both period and hyphen-delimited.

I have a (MySQL) data-set like this (using SQLAlchemy to access it):

```
id    text        tag
====================================
1     some-text   A.B.c3
2     more. text  A.B-C.c4
3     even more.  B.A-32.D-24.f9
```

The core reason I use ES for search in the first place is that I want to query against the `text` field.  That part works awesome!

But, (I think) I want the the `tag` to appear in the inverted index like this (I probably won't take case into account, just including it for illustration):

```
A.B.c3            1
A.B-C.c4          2
B.A-C2.D-24.f9    3
```

Then, I want to search the `tag` field like this:

```
{ "query": {
      "prefix" : { "tag" : "A.B" }
    }
}
```

And have the query return `id`/rows/documents 1 and 2.

Basically, I want the query to match the index(es) in this truth table:

```
"A." = 1, 2
"A-" = 3
```

How do I accomplish both the "`A.`" match at the beginning, differentiate between a period and a hyphen (possibly boost this), and match mid-phrase based on those same delimiters?

I'd also like to weight these matches higher if they occur at the beginning of the `tag` field if possible.

How do I do this, or is Elasticsearch not the right tool for the job?  It seems like Elasticsearch works great for my text-field comparisons on normally delimited English text, but the tag-based searches seem much harder.

**UPDATE:** It seems that when I index only a subset of the data that my searches return the results I would expect but when querying against the full data-set, I get fewer hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via [N-Gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer.

Based on what you've provided in question, I've created its corresponding mapping, documents and a sample query to give you what you are looking for.

### Mapping

```
PUT idtesttag
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "tag": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this would do is, if you have a document with `id = 1` has a tag `A.B` it would store following group of characters in its inverted index.

```
 A. -> 1
 .B -> 1
A.B -> 1
```

So if your query has any of these three words, your document with `id=1` would be returned.

### Sample Documents

```
POST idtesttag/mydocs/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "some-text",
  "tag": "A.B.c3"
}

POST idtesttag/mydocs/2
{
  "id": 2,
  "text": "more. text",
  "tag": "A.B-C.c4"
}

POST idtesttag/mydocs/3
{
  "id": 3,
  "text": "even more.",
  "tag": "B.A-32.D-24.f9"
}

POST idtesttag/mydocs/4
{
  "id": 3,
  "text": "even more.",
  "tag": "B.A.B-32.D-24.f9"
}
```

### Sample Query

```
POST idtesttag/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tag": "A.B"
    }
  }
}
```

### Query Response

```
{
  "took": 139,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.8630463,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "idtesttag",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "text": "some-text",
          "tag": "A.B.c3"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idtesttag",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.66078395,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "more. text",
          "tag": "A.B-C.c4"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idtesttag",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.46659434,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3,
          "text": "even more.",
          "tag": "B.A.B-32.D-24.f9"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the documents 1, 2 and 4 are returned in the response. The `document 4` is the *mid sentence match* while documents `1 & 2` are at the beginning.

Also note the score value as how it appears.

### Boosting based on hypen

Now with regards to boosting based on `hypen` character, I'd suggest you to have [Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query along with [Regex Query with Boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html). Below is the sample query I came up with.

Note that just for sake of simplicity I've added regex where it would only boost if hypen is next to `A.B`.

```
POST idtesttag/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : {
        "match" : { "tag" : "A.B" }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "tag": {
              "value": "A.B-.*",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Boosting Query Response

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 3.660784,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "idtesttag",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 3.660784,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "more. text",
          "tag": "A.B-C.c4"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idtesttag",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 3.4665942,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3,
          "text": "even more.",
          "tag": "B.A.B-32.D-24.f9"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idtesttag",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "text": "some-text",
          "tag": "A.B.c3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Just ensure that your testing is thorough when it comes to boosting because its all about influencing the score & make sure you do that with prod data ingested in DEV/TEST Elastic index.

That way you'd not be spooked when you see totally different results if you move to PROD Elastic.

I'm sorry its pretty long answer but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> But, (I think) I want the the tag to appear in the inverted index like this (I probably won't take case into account, just including it for illustration):
>
> Then, I want to search the tag field like this:

Based on what you've described in your post reg. the 'tag' field, here's my 2 cents.

Your Mysql data should be in 1 type (in 6.5 it's 'doc' by default). You do need to explicitly define your Index Mapping though - especially on the 'tag' field, as you seem to have search requirements.

I would define your 'tag' field as a multi-field of:

- type 'keyword' for aggregations
- type 'text' for searches, with a custom analyzer (that might use 'whitespace' tokenizer, and an 'edge ngram' token filter

*(if you don't need aggregations, then just define a 'text' type field with the custom analyzer)*

FYI, The [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) will show you what ES is doing with your 'tag' data, and will help you define the Mapping that meets your requirements.